# html assigning value to input text using javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, html, input, assign

**I am new to programming and I have a small problem**

I have a form named "fr" with an input text box named "in" and a variable "n" with the value of "my text"
this is my code what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var n = "my text";
document.fr.in.value = n;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="fr">
<input name="in" size="3">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

but somehow input "in" does not show the text "my text"
I have been browsing the internet but I couldn't find any solution which works..
everything what I try does not work.
I think I am doing something very simple wrong.
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should init the script after the form is defined, as explained by Paul S. in his answer. So you may do,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form name="fr">
<input name="in" size="3">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var n = "my text";
document.forms.fr.in.value = n;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This would run the script after the form is defined. Or put this code in some function, and instantiate the function after the form is defined(i.e. loaded).

Comment: This will still throw the same _TypeError_

Answer (score 3):

`document.fr` does not exist yet at time of invocation; hence, everything following it doesn't exist either, so it throws a *TypeError*

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'in' of undefined
```

To fix this, move your code to be invoked after the nodes exist, using your favourite method

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var n = "my text";
    document.fr.in.value = n;
});
```

---

I'll further note that;

1. The preferred way to look up an *Element* is to give it an *id* attribute and use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById). An *id* must be unique.
2. Using the *language* attribute of [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) is *depreciated*, if you want to specify the language, use the *type* attribute `type="text/javascript"` or `type="application/javascript"`
3. [Opening the *Console*](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) when a script is not working as expected will often show you the cause immediately. This is usually done with <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul pointed out you should only try to get a hold of page elements when you are certain that the element you are interested has already been loaded. So in this case you can set the value of the input field by running your code when the page has fully loaded and by getting a reference to the input like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var n = "my text";
    var myInput = document.getElementsByName("in");
    myInput[0].value = n;
});
```

Note, because `getElementsByName()` returns an array, you will have to use [0], to get the first element.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`